# Output to multiple divs using getElementsByClassName?

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbyclassname

I want to output to multiple elements using JavaScript. The following example may show what i want.

```
<select id="leave" onchange="leaveChange()">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="150">EMS</option>
  <option value="350">DHL</option>
  <option value="200">UPS</option>
  <option value="75">Ethiopia Postal</option>
</select>
<script>
function leaveChange() {
    if (document.getElementById("leave").value == document.getElementById("leave").value){
        document.getElementsByClassName("item_shipping")[0].innerHTML = document.getElementById("leave").value;
    }     
    else{
        document.getElementById("item_shipping").innerHTML = 0;
    }        
}

</script>
<div class="item_shipping"></div> //this is getting value
<div class="item_shipping"></div> //this i empty i want the same value?
```

The first `div` show the result but the second one is empty. How do I update both?

Comment: If you are using getElementsByClassName then you need to iterate over the returned collection object and set the value

Comment: what is the purpose of the `if` condition?

Comment: @Arun you can modify the code but the output class is the same `<div class="item_shipping"></div>` and 2nd `<div class="item_shipping"></div>`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2hed87bp/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function leaveChange() {
        var leaveValue = document.getElementById("leave").value;
        var shippingItems = document.getElementsByClassName("item_shipping");

        for (var i = 0; i < shippingItems.length; i++) {
            if (leaveValue == leaveValue) // ??
                shippingItems[i].innerHTML = leaveValue;
            else
                shippingItems[i].innerHTML = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Dear @Alex R tks let ask u question this code for shopping cart many item different shipping method as it see above. 1st item EMS 2nd item DHL that mean `<div class="item_shipping"></div>` value 150, 350 respectively how do make the same div class different value? tks